# ¿Qué es "engavetar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, etimología, cuba

Estaba leyendo [un artículo](http://www.granma.cu/mundo/2016-05-12/por-que-fracasaron-los-benjamines-12-05-2016-23-05-09) en un periódico cubano y me encontré con el siguiente parágrafo:

> Este político (...) alcanzó cierta notoriedad como integrante de la
>   llamada “pandilla de los ocho”, un grupo de senadores (cuatro
>   demócratas y cuatro republicanos) quienes elaboraron y propusieron un
>   proyecto (...) el cual fue aprobado (...) pero quedó **engavetado** en
>   la Cámara de Representantes (...) a pesar de que el propio Rubio
>   también se pronunció a favor de **engavetar** la propuesta de ley ya
>   aprobada por el Senado, valiéndole acusaciones de “cambiacasacas”.

En él me costó entender la palabra *engavetar*, por lo que busqué y vi que el DRAE lo recoge:

> **[engavetar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FMbikWn)**
>
> 1. tr. Cuba, El Salv., Nic., R. Dom. y Ven. Detener o paralizar un asunto o un documento voluntariamente.
> 2. tr. El Salv., Guat., Hond. y Ven. Guardar algo en una gaveta por tiempo indefinido.

Lo que me hizo descubrir la palabra gaveta:

> **[gaveta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0r3NQr)**
>
> Del it. gavetta.
>
> 1. f. Cajón corredizo que hay en los escritorios y sirve para guardar lo que se quiere tener a mano.
>
> (...)
>
> 5. f. Cuba. guantera (‖ caja del salpicadero).

Así que una vez entendido el significado, veo que se refiere a detener, parar un proceso. Sin embargo, persiste mi duda: ¿en qué contexto se usa? ¿Solamente en ambiente formal? ¿Hay alguna otra palabra no tan formal, si es el caso?

Nunca lo había oído nombrar, ¿por qué se habla de *gaveta* si es una palabra italiana? ¿Acaso es un mueble sumamente famoso en la zona?

Comment: En pocas palabras, y como podrás deducir a partir de las definiciones que has recogido, significa 'archivar', bien sea en un sentido metafórico(como el artículo que mencionas) o literal(al guardar un documento en la gaveta, que no es otra cosa que un cajón o archivero bien de un escritorio o algún otro mueble similar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En Colombia, tiene el mismo significado: *aplazar, postponer*.

La palabra "gaveta" es sinomino de "cajón".  De hecho algunas personas se refieren a un mueble con cajones para almacenamiento como gavetero o cajonera.

Comment: Amplío como comentario que en Argentina se usa el mismo concepto con la palabra ***encajonar*** (sinónimo de ese uso cubano referido aquí—por enlentecer, demorar, postergar indefinidamete un proyecto legislativo, dormir un caso sensible en la justicia etc.

Answer (score 0):

Según tengo entendido gaveta se refiere a un cajón o a la guantera del copiloto del coche.
"Aquí no hay miedo lo dejamos en la gaveta" decía Hector El Father refiriéndose como se supone a que dejaba encajonado el miedo (o el arma en la guantera del copiloto)

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al sitio, Fer! Fíjate que fedorqui ya resolvió el significado de las palabras _gaveta_ y _engavetar_ en la pregunta, y lo que realmente quiere saber es si dichas palabras se usan solo en contextos formales, o si se puede ampliar su uso a otros contextos coloquiales, y en caso negativo qué otras palabras menos coloquiales existen que sean sinónimas. Si conoces la respuesta a estas preguntas, puedes [edit]ar tu respuesta y añadir dicha información, y así te quedará redonda.